# how to wrap text in tooltip in WPF given that we are using tooltip through style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
 <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding PropertyOne, 
  Converter={StaticResource SettingsToDescriptionConverter}}"/>                                                      
</Style>
```

i am using this style in ElementStyle of extendedDataGrid.

I have tried this-

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip.Style" Value="{StaticResource tooltipstyle}"/>
```

but it gives error that we can not use style within style.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can declare `Style` of `ToolTip` in `App.xaml` file and apply `Style` of `ToolTip` whenever you want by using `x:Key property`:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="fooToolTip">
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="20" />
        <!--OR-->
        <!--<Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{Binding Path=(lib:ToolTipProperties.MaxWidth)}" />-->
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            </Style>
                        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Your example:

```
<Label Content="For ToolTip">
    <Label.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource fooTooltip}">
           <TextBlock>This is the Wrapped Tooltip</TextBlock>
        </ToolTip>
    </Label.ToolTip>
</Label>
```

Comment: @traveller feel free to ask any questions:). You can accept my reply as answer to simplify search by other people.